# Javascript match and regularexpression

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I've searched for an example, but I'm so bad at Regular Expressions that I really need an answer to my specific example.
I'm using JavaScript and have the following string as an example:
`accountActivityStatus.transactionHistorys.0.activityAmt`

I need to be able to match that any given string starts with `accountActivityStatus` and contains a number somewhere after that.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated:

Answer (score 0):

```
^accountActivityStatus(?=.*\d).*$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yZ7qJ6/7

```
var re = /^accountActivityStatus(?=.*\d).*$/gm;
var str = 'accountActivityStatus.transactionHistorys.0.activityAmt\naccountActivityStatus.transactionHistorys..activityAmt\naccountActivityStatus.transactionHistorys.4.activityAmt';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: any reason for the lookahead on this? I think it'll work the same even if you remove it. ie `^accountActivityStatus.*\d.*$`